# Getting issue Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string' in React Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am getting issue like Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string' in React Typescript. The value is coming as string so I assign the type as string but I am getting this error for some reason. Here is the code. Can you please tell me what is the issue with the below code ?

usePrice.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useCurrency } from './useCurrency';

export interface PropsFunc {
  langCode: string;
  localCurrency: string;
  employees: number;
  breach: boolean;
}

export interface IFetchError {
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
}

export const usePrice = ({
  langCode,
  localCurrency,
  employees,
  breach,
}: PropsFunc) => {
  const [totalCost, setTotalCost] = useCurrency(langCode, localCurrency, 0);

  const calculatedPrice = () => {
    let price;
    // some logic to calculation
    return price;
  };

  const setPricesData = (products) => {
     // logic to set price
  };

  const fetchPrices = async (localCurrency: string) => {
    fetch(
      `api calling`,
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setPricesData(data))
      .catch((error) => setFetchingError(error.response));
  };

  const price = calculatedPrice();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPrices(localCurrency);
  }, [localCurrency]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTotalCost(price);
  }, [employees, breach, ruMonthlySublistPrice]);

  return [totalCost, fetchingError];
};
```

useCurrency.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import lngToHtmlLang from '../lib/lngToHtmlLang';
import currenciesList from '../services/currencies.json';

// US default
const formatUSD = (price: number, numberFormat: Intl.NumberFormat) => {
  const formattedValue = numberFormat.formatToParts(price);
  return formattedValue
    .map(({ type, value }) => (type === 'currency' ? 'US$' : value))
    .reduce((string, part) => string + part);
};

// switch local Dollar currency
const formatCurrency = (
  price: number,
  numberFormat: Intl.NumberFormat,
  currency: string,
): string => {
  switch (currency) {
    case 'USD':
      return formatUSD(price, numberFormat);
    default:
      return numberFormat.format(price);
  }
};

type CurrencyList = {
  countryName: string;
  countryLang: string;
  country: string;
  currency: string;
};

export const useCurrency = (
  intl: string,
  lang: string,
  price: number,
): [string, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>] => {
  const [rawValue, setRawValue] = useState(price);
  const [formattedValue, setFormattedValue] = useState('');

  const corrspondingCountryCurrency = currenciesList.find(
    (object: CurrencyList) => {
      return object.countryLang === lang;
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!rawValue) {
      setFormattedValue('');
    } else {
      const currency = corrspondingCountryCurrency?.currency;
      const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat(lngToHtmlLang(lang), {
        style: 'currency',
        currency,
        currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
        minimumFractionDigits: 0,
      });

      const formatted = formatCurrency(
        rawValue,
        numberFormat,
        currency as string,
      );
      setFormattedValue(formatted);
    }
  }, [lang, rawValue, corrspondingCountryCurrency]);

  return [formattedValue, setRawValue];
};
```

This is my app file
App.js

```
const [totalCost] = usePrice({
    langCode, 
    localCurrency,
    employees,
    breach,
  });

return (
          <Thanks
          totalCost={totalCost} // Getting issue here like Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string' in React Typescript
        />
)

export default App;
```

Thanks.js

```
/* eslint-disable formatjs/enforce-id */
import { ReactElement, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Column, Grid, Row, Button} from 'carbon-components-react';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import messages from '../locales/messages';

export interface thanksProps {
  totalCost: string;
}

const Thanks = ({
  totalCost,
}: thanksProps): ReactElement => {
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollTo('ThankYou');
  }, []);

  return (
    <Grid id="ThankYou">
      <Row>
        <Column sm={4} md={8} lg={12}>
              <p style={{ lineHeight: '1.7' }}>
                <FormattedMessage {...messages.estimatedCosts} />:{' '}
                <strong>{totalCost}</strong>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Column>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Thanks;
```

I have assign type to totalCost as string in Thanks component but still I am getting issue. Although I check the typeof total cost which is coming as string .

Answer (score 0):

Try next thing in `return` statement of your `App.js` file:
instead of
`totalCost={totalCost}` write `totalCost={{totalCost}}`

Comment: still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in formatUSD function. You are using reduce there, but you did not specify initial value for it.

```
const formatUSD = (price: number, numberFormat: Intl.NumberFormat) => {
  const formattedValue = numberFormat.formatToParts(price);

  return formattedValue
    .map(({ type, value }) => (type === 'currency' ? 'US$' : value))
    .reduce((string, part) => (string + part), '');
};
```

Try changing it by adding empty string as a second parameter.